# How to get objects and VBA functions to work in Excel for Office 365?

Tags: excel, vba, button, hyperlink, office365

Created a workbook in Excel desktop that uses buttons and hyperlinks to run VBA functions. When 
workbook loaded in browser-based Office 365, buttons do not appear and clicking hyperlinks gives

`Sorry, we couldn't open this link. The link address may be invalid, or you may not have permission to open it.`

How do I get desktop hyperlink and button functionality to port to Office 365?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-vba-macros-in-excel-for-the-web-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us. VBA doesn't work in Excel online. Check out the [Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview).

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a Web add-in if you want to get your extra functionality working everywhere, see [Excel add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview). VBA is for Windows desktop applications only.